# PHP code on the top and echo somewhere else

Tags: php, database

I have this code on the top of page:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

if(!isset($_SESSION['IS_LOGEDIN']))
{
    $_SESSION['IS_LOGEDIN'] = 'N';
}
// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($myusername));
$mypassword = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword));

$encrypted_mypassword=md5($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM administratori WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$encrypted_mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['IS_LOGEDIN'] = 'Y';
//$lastlogin = $_POST['date("d/m/y  H:i:s", time()+25200)'];
header("location:administrare.php");
}
else {
echo '<img src="images/delete.png" width="16" height="16" />' . '&nbsp;' .'User sau Password gresit!';
}
}
?>
```

What I need to do to display that `echo` in the HTML form? because the echo is displaying on the top of the page. Please help me! :)

Comment: The `stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($myusername))` looks like a mistake. Maybe it should be ` mysql_real_escape_string($myusername)` (if magic_quotes_gpc is off) or possibly `mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($myusername))` (if magic_quotes_gpc is on, which is something I strongly discourage).

Comment: You should also not be using `mysql_` extension. The sooner you start using `mysqli_` or `PDO`, the better (less code you'll have to change later). And I strongly recommend going with the object oriented approach and using prepared statements in any production code instead of using `real_escape_string`

Comment: This is coming from the first find when you google: php login tutorial, see it coming by every now and then, outdated as hell.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

if(!isset($_SESSION['IS_LOGEDIN']))
{
    $_SESSION['IS_LOGEDIN'] = 'N';
}
// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($myusername));
$mypassword = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword));

$encrypted_mypassword=md5($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM administratori WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$encrypted_mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['IS_LOGEDIN'] = 'Y';
//$lastlogin = $_POST['date("d/m/y  H:i:s", time()+25200)'];
header("location:administrare.php");
}
else {
$img='<img src="images/delete.png" width="16" height="16" />' . '&nbsp;' .'User sau Password gresit!';
}
}
?>
```

your html code here....

```
<?php echo $img; ?>
```

rest of your html code....

Comment: [Short open tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) is an option, too. ie `<?=$img?>`, as long as short open tags are enabled in the ini_settings for php version 5.3 or less, or if the PHP version is 5.4 or greater, then `<?=` is always available

Answer (score 0):

Just place the test inside your form :

```
if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['IS_LOGEDIN'] = 'Y';
//$lastlogin = $_POST['date("d/m/y  H:i:s", time()+25200)'];
header("location:administrare.php"); 
}
else {
echo '<img src="images/delete.png" width="16" height="16" />' . '&nbsp;' .'User sau Password    gresit!';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply just post this to your form area.

```
if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['IS_LOGEDIN'] = 'Y';
//$lastlogin = $_POST['date("d/m/y  H:i:s", time()+25200)'];
header("location:administrare.php");
}
else {
echo '<img src="images/delete.png" width="16" height="16" />' . '&nbsp;' .'User sau Password gresit!';
}
```

Or if you want you can use jquery
Use the code below for php

```
if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['IS_LOGEDIN'] = 'Y';
//$lastlogin = $_POST['date("d/m/y  H:i:s", time()+25200)'];
header("location:administrare.php");
}
else {
echo '<div id="test"><img src="images/delete.png" id="image1" width="16" height="16" /></div>' . '&nbsp;' .'User sau Password gresit!';
}
```

Use the code below for jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var r = $("#test").html();
$("#formid").append(r);
});
</script>
```

It's working fine Have a look at it here http://jsfiddle.net/n2zmno6v/1/

Hope this helps you